# Problems loading iOS solutions in Xamarin Studio on Mac

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono

I am having issues opening/running iOS projects in Xamarin Studio. I have installed all of the available packages when I did the original installation and they all show when I go to "About Xamarin Studio Community" (see below). But when I go to open any demo solutions, the iOS projects are grayed out with a warning symbol that says "This project type requires Xamarin.iOS to be installed". Any help would be appreciated!

> === Xamarin Studio Community ===
>
> Version 6.1.1 (build 15) Installation UUID:
>   75216407-8d10-456c-a3f6-52b42cad7e92 Runtime: Mono 4.6.1
>   (mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/abb06f1) (64-bit) GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh
>   theme)
>
> Package version: 406010003
>   === NuGet ===
>
> Version: 3.4.3.0
>
> === Xamarin.Profiler ===
>
> Not Installed
>
> === Apple Developer Tools ===
>
> Xcode 6.3.2 (7718) Build 6D2105
>
> === Xamarin.Mac ===
>
> Version: 2.10.0.103 (Xamarin Studio Community)
>
> === Xamarin.iOS ===
>
> Version: 10.0.1.8 (Xamarin Studio Community) Hash: 3983064 Branch:
>   cycle8-sr0-xi Build date: 2016-09-23 15:34:54-0400
>
> === Xamarin.Android ===
>
> Version: 7.0.0.18 (Xamarin Studio Community) Android SDK:
>   /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx Supported
>   Android versions:
>   6.0 (API level 23)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 25.1.2 SDK Platform Tools Version: 24.0.0 SDK Build
>   Tools Version: 23.0.2
>
> Java SDK: /usr java version "1.7.0_71" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   (build 1.7.0_71-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
>   24.71-b01, mixed mode)
>
> Android Designer EPL code available here:
>   https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL
>
> === Xamarin Android Player ===
>
> Version: 0.6.5 Location: /Applications/Xamarin Android Player.app
>
> === Build Information ===
>
> Release ID: 601010015 Git revision:
>   fa52f02641726146e2589ed86ec4097fbe101888 Build date: 2016-09-22
>   08:03:02-04 Xamarin addins: 75d65712af93d54dc39ae4c42b21dfa574859fd6
>   Build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle8-sr0
>
> === Operating System ===
>
> Mac OS X 10.11.6 Darwin MacBook-Pro.local 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel
>   Version 15.6.0

Comment: Xcode needs updated: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/

Comment: @SushiHangover that was the answer!  Thanks! If you want to create an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SushiHangover stated, Xcode needed to be updated and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and found that an upgrade (XCode or MacOS; not sure) moved XCode on me.

Go to Menu --> Preferences --> Projects --> SDK Locations --> Apple

and make sure the location points to Xcode.app.

Comment: Thank you! You save me a lot of time!)